# How to set the default icon in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jframe

So I was making Java, and made a nice little program. Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class aa extends JFrame{
    private JButton jb;
    private JTextField jt0;
    private JTextField jt1;
    private JTextField jt2;
    int jti1;
    int jti2;

    public aa(){
        jb = new JButton(">> FIGHT <<");
        jt0 = new JTextField("", 25);
        jt1 = new JTextField("", 25);
        jt2 = new JTextField("<< BATTLE VICTOR >>", 35);    
        jt0.setText("");
        jt2.setEditable(false);

        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(jt0.getText().length() > jt1.getText().length())
                    jt2.setText((jt0.getText() + " << IS VICTORIUS OVER >> " + jt1.getText()));
                else if(jt1.getText().length() > jt0.getText().length())
                    jt2.setText((jt1.getText() + " << IS VICTORIUS OVER >> " + jt0.getText()));
                else if(jt1.getText().length() == jt0.getText().length())
                    jt2.setText((jt1.getText() + " << TIED >> " + jt0.getText()));
            };
        }
        );

        add(jt0, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(jt1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(jt2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(jb, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

And here is the running script:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class a{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        aa b = new aa();

        b.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        b.setTitle("BattleWords");
        b.setSize(420, 150);
        b.setVisible(true);
        b.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

}

I have so far tried the whole `setIconImage()` crap and it did not work. I want to add in a png or gif or ico image. Where should I place it? Where does the code go and how can it look like?

Comment: That "setIconImage crap" is what you need to do. Perhaps you were doing it wrong? Show us some sample code with the non-working code. Also, where was the image file in your folder hierarchy?

Comment: import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

 public class b extends JFrame{
  private JTextField jt;

  public b(){
   jt = new JTextField();
   jt.setText("Hello World!");
   
   //'Set icon crap'
  }
 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do in fact use `JFrame.setIconImage()`. Here is an example of code which could appear in the constructor of your `JFrame` or even better in an `initComponents` method:

```
try {
    Image image = ImageIO.read(aa.class.getResource("/TestImage.png"));
    setIconImage(image);
} (IOException e) {
   // handle exception
}
```

The image `TestImage.png` would be located in the root folder where your class files are located. This

Comment: It says "Unhandled exception type IOException"

Comment: That error doesnt tell much. Did you copy the image into the class root folder?

Comment: I added it to src. all of the .java's are in there.

Comment: No, it (the image) would be in the `bin` folder

Comment: Don't know that you can. It scales everything down to fit.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a folder outside your sources then put the icon image in there. Then, use this code to load your icon.

```
b.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(new File("res/icon.png")));
```

I use this and it works every time.